# how get and expand last grid in tailwind

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

hello guys how can get the last grid, i dont know the number to get images can be more than 3 least 5, i want to make the last grid image full using tailwind css

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 mx-auto">
                @foreach ( $post->images as $image )
                <div class="w-full">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/storage/' . $image->filename) }}" alt="" class="w-full rounded-md h-36">
                </div>

                @endforeach
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable available in Blade.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 mx-auto">
    @foreach ( $post->images as $image )
    <div class="@if ($loop->last) w-full @endif">
        <img src="{{ asset('/storage/' . $image->filename) }}" alt="" class="w-full rounded-md h-36">
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: that did not work

Comment: Can you elaborate on how id `"did not work"`?